# how to extract Id of one url in one to another url in 2nd html page using angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
<a href="productview.html?sku" ng-click="retrive_click">
    <div ng-repeat="product in products" class='custom-products'>
        <div class='custom-products custom-products-image'>
            <img src='{{product.image_url}}' />
        </div>
        <div class='custom-products custom-products-currency'>
            <span>{{product.price}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

On ng button click want to get id of sku to another page

Need your help

Comment: How??? The ng-click is not inside the ng-repeat loop

Comment: rephrase your question description.. try to be more descriptive..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your ID (in your case your sku) in another view you can do it using $routeProvider.

Here I show you an example on JSFiddle

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/list.html">
        <h4>List</h4>
        <a href="#/detail/1" class="btn">One</a>
        <a href="#/detail/2" class="btn">Two</a>
        <a href="#/detail/3" class="btn">Three</a>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/detail.html">
        <h4>Id from the other view is  {{id}}</h4>
    </script>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []).config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/list', {
        templateUrl: '/list.html'
    })
    .when('/detail/:id/', {
        templateUrl: '/detail.html',
        controller: 'DetailCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/list'
    });
});

myapp.controller('DetailCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.id = ($routeParams.id) ? parseInt($routeParams.id) : 0;
});
```

[Test here](http://jsfiddle.net/gumarelo/m5h2pskk/)